# Android - Actionbar not showing in the development preview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Actionbar not showing in the development preview but showing normally after running the app, minimum api is 15, tried to delete the them from the manifest file, didn't show the actionbar, and can't run the app anymore.

It is a completely new project (tried deleting it and recreating it and creating several other with different minimum api, still not showing in the development)

My theme is blank with a parent "parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar""

Trying to use a holo light theme, crashed and got that error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Default activity extends actionbaractivity instead of activity, fixed now. Thanks

Comment: Please add some more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check which **theme** is selected on the top of the XML preview screen.

[image]

Even if you're using Eclipse, it will look similar.

Your application is displaying the ActionBar because your AndroidManifest has a theme which displays the ActionBar.

Comment: Holo light is working, but all of appcompact aren't, appcompact doesn't have an actionbar?

Comment: Trying to use a holo light theme, crashed and got that error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Comment: Change the Java inheritance from ActionBarActivity to Activity and leave the dialog theme in the manifest as it is.

Comment: If it works please thumbs up and accept as the correct answer

Answer (score 53):

If you can't see the action bar AND also the status bar or buttons, it could be because the "Show Layout Decorations" options is turned off in the Layout Editor. Just check this option and everything should be displayed again. As per Android Studio 3.3:

[image: Turning on Layout Decorations in Android Studio 3.3]

Comment: That indeed was it on AS 3.3.1. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, this seems to be the default in newer Android Studio versions for some reason.

Comment: In the latest version (as of 25 Aug 2020) the option is 'Show System UI'.

Comment: in Android 4.1.3 its "Show System UI"

Answer (score 1):

try this

**values/themes.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.Mytheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

 </style>
```

and **assigns the item in the manifest**

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Mytheme">
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about the preview screen of the android studio/eclipse then note that you can change your theme in the top of the preview, you must have a theme with NoActionBar .