# No Action bar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

If I make a new project in Android Studio 3.3.1, with Empty activity. There is no Action Bar in the design tab and in the preview too.
[image]
[image]

This is my style.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Post your `styles.xml` file.

Comment: Under Palette click Containers. There you will find Toolbar.

Comment: I added the style.xml

Comment: When I run the app I see the action bar

Comment: did you tried by changing theme? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410005/android-actionbar-not-showing-in-the-development-preview

Comment: Thanks! There was another answer, "show layout decoration".