# Android Studio preview is not showing ActionBar

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I was updated my Android Studio. Android Studio creates issue in Android preview
Android actionbar can't show I don't know what's the issue I tried many times but failed. Action and header doesn't show:
[image: action and header can't show]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Actionbar not showing in the development preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410005/android-actionbar-not-showing-in-the-development-preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure Show Layout Decorations is checked under the preview panel.

[image: Show Layout decorations]

Comment: @HaiderShahHashmi mark my question as correct so that others can also benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

please check your **AppTheme** in **style.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use Android Studio v4.1.1 under the "Show system UI" preview panel.

[image]